# « Fit-il pas mieux que de se plaindre ? »

Tags: grammaire, négation, questions

[*Le Renard et les Raisins*](http://lcweb2.loc.gov/cgi-bin/ampage?collId=rbc3&fileName=rbc0001_2003holmes80074page.db&recNum=15) est la fable la plus [courte](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Renard_et_les_Raisins) de [*Jean de La Fontaine*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_de_La_Fontaine) (voir [aussi](http://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Fables_d%E2%80%99%C3%89sope/Le_Renard_et_les_Raisins)). Elle compte uniquement 8 vers:

> Certain renard gascon, d'autres disent normand,
>  Mourant presque
>   de faim, vit au haut d'une treille
>  Des raisins mûrs
>   apparemment,
>  Et couverts d'une peau vermeille.
>  Le galant en
>   eût fait volontiers un repas ;
>  Mais comme il n'y pouvait
>   atteindre :
>  « Ils sont trop verts, dit-il, et bons pour des
>   goujats. » 
>  **Fit-il pas mieux que de se plaindre ?**
>
> [ Le Renard et les Raisins(XI), *Fables de La Fontaine*, Recueil I, Livre
>   III, Jean de La Fontaine, 1668 ]

Pourquoi l'auteur a-t-il omis la particule *ne* devant le verbe pour ensuite utiliser « pas mieux » dans son interrogation ?  Est-ce que le sens est différent de « n'est-ce (pas) là mieux que de se plaindre ? »; si oui, à quel égard, et sinon, pourquoi cette tournure ?

Comment: Comment-worthy at best, but “fit-il” (il=le renard) could perhaps be read as being more critical of the fox & his rationalizing than “n’est-ce pas.” To me, “N’était-ce pas mieux que de se plaindre” is more of a general (& positive) observation that “Rationalizing is better than whining” = “Was/is it not better (to claim sour grapes) than to whine (about them being out of reach)?”, whereas “Fit-il pas mieux que de se plaindre,” directed more specifically at what the fox did, could be more easily interpreted as a neutral question w/no positive spin: “Did he do no better (or worse) than whining?”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectivement, La Fontaine omet ici un « ne », tout simplement pour respecter le nombre de pieds (huit) du vers.

Fit est le passé simple, troisième personne du singulier. Si l’on voulait plutôt employer une tournure utilisant un « N’est-ce pas », il faudrait, pour respecter la concordance des temps, employer l’imparfait, ce qui donnerait quelque chose comme :

> N’était-ce pas mieux que de se plaindre ?

Au delà d’éventuels problèmes de styles, encore une fois l’on obtient une phrase qui ne fait pas huit pieds. Remarquons que le problème subsiste en employant le présent.

Answer (score 2):

Le [nombre de pieds](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13212) joue certainement un rôle; d'autre part certains vers sont en alexandrin. Mais pourquoi pas, par exemple, « *Ne fit-il pas mieux que se plaindre ?* » pour le même nombre de pieds, la préposition *de* étant [facultative](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mieux) avec *mieux que*. J'ai une hésitation à la lecture du dernier vers avec ce « *fit-il* ». :

*Faire comme dire*. Le verbe [*faire*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faire) à ce temps, en incise, après une citation ou une onomatopée, c'est l'équivalent de *dire* ou exprimer - tel « dit-il ». Le « ne » l'empêcherait, mais de toutes façons la ponctuation s'y oppose ici, puisque la citation est introduite par le deux-points, qu'elle se termine par un point, et qu'il n'y a pas d'incise qui serait identifiée par une virgule après « *fit-il* »; sauf qu'à la lecture un lecteur pourrait avoir le réflexe d'effectuer une courte pause. La différence serait peut-être alors que dans cette dernière incantation la formule constituerait une affirmation et que *La Fontaine* nous mettrait le point d'interrogation pour la forme; ce serait une forme d’offuscation.

*Les autres sens de faire* (à l'entrée du *TLFi*). D'autre part, on ne se surprendra pas qu'une multitude de sens soient aussi à la portée du verbe *faire*, comme *présenter(un aspect physique, extérieur)*/*jouer le rôle*, ou *avoir pour variante(en grammaire)/équivaloir*, ou même encore la maladie psychique (*faire une dépression* etc.). Il y a aussi des sens avec l'idée de nettoyer (les chaussures etc.), jusqu'au culinaire, dans le sens d'apprêter. Enfin, on retrouve imiter, avoir l'air, paraître. Sans savoir si tous ces emplois étaient accessibles à, et voulus par, l'auteur, j'y reconnaîtrais volontiers son génie à les faire collaborer par son choix de tournure. On peut aussi se poser des questions sur l'utilisation de faire en auxiliaire dans la construction « *ne faire que* » avec les idées de *n'avoir d'autre effet que*, *se contenter de* et la construction « *ne faire que de* » dans le sens de *venir a peine de*. Par ailleurs, *en faire autant* c'est *ni mieux ni plus mal*, et *on ne fait pas mieux* indique que c'est ce qu'il y a de plus estimable, de *meilleur*. Cette idée de comparaison pourrait ressembler à la forme particulière où le verbe *faire* vient remplacer un verbe utilisé précédemment (*Après m'avoir engraissé comme on fait les oies* (Mérimée, *Lettres Panizzi*,t. 2, 1870, p. 127).); ici ce serait le verbe *dire* sous-entendu ([il dit]: citation + faire) et donne donc un truc comme « *il dit [citation] comme fait celui qui se plaint* »; c'est-à-dire à chacun ses mots, mais aux prises avec les même maux! En effet le « glorieux » s'en sent-il mieux de faire tel celui qui méprise le fruit qu'il désire ? Et a-t-il davantage de raisins ?

---

<sub>Quelques notes d'accompagnement. Sur [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_de_style), le dernier vers sert d'exemple pour l'interpellation feinte d'une question rhétorique. [Comparaison](http://ww3.ac-poitiers.fr/lettres/lang_anc/ephedre.htm) avec éléments latins. [Normand et Gascon](http://www.lafontaine.net/lesFables/afficheFable.php?id=54). Une courte [analyse](http://www.petitchosier.fr/blog/post/2011/12/08/Le-Renard-et-les-raisins). [Réinterprétation](http://danielebd.com/bd-comics/bdcomics-3) amusante. Et à mon avis les [psychologues](https://books.google.ca/books?id=V1uRLtHrhOwC&lpg=PA233&ots=a3Vh68T8XK&dq=%22fit-il%20pas%20mieux%20que%20de%20se%20plaindre%22%20analyse&pg=PA233#v=onepage&q=%22fit-il%20pas%20mieux%20que%20de%20se%20plaindre%22%20analyse&f=false) n'y ont rien compris.</sub>