# Understanding "de" in "plus facile, cependant, que de remuer le soleil"

Tags: prépositions, verbes, infinitif

The question is on *de* as highlighted in this passage from [L’Éducation sentimentale](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/L%E2%80%99%C3%89ducation_sentimentale,_%C3%A9d._Conard,_1910/I/I) by Flaubert.

> Une plaine s’étendait à droite ; à gauche un herbage allait doucement rejoindre une colline, où l’on apercevait des vignobles, des noyers, un moulin dans la verdure, et des petits chemins au delà, formant des zigzags sur la roche blanche qui touchait au bord du ciel. Quel bonheur de monter côte à côte, le bras autour de sa taille, pendant que sa robe balayerait les feuilles jaunies, en écoutant sa voix, sous le rayonnement de ses yeux ! Le bateau pouvait s’arrêter, ils n’avaient qu’à descendre ; et cette chose bien simple n’était pas plus facile, cependant, que **de** remuer le soleil !

**Question**

1. What is its grammatical or syntactic function?  (For example, is there a *de*-infinitive similar to the English *to*-infinitive?)
2. Would it be acceptable to delete *de* in the Flaubert sentence (i.e. have *que remuer le soleil* instead)?  Would that be ungrammatical?  Would it be grammatical but change the meaning?
3. What would be other usages for *de* + an infinitive?  I.e. please give other sentence forms in which *de* would have the same syntactic role as described in answer to question 1.

**Background**

It's possible that an answer to my question is already contained in [this earlier post](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19226/the-present-infinitive-as-a-noun), but that I am just not being able to see it.

Comment: There is no function here. There is a comparative form using a verb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1- In the sentence

> Il est facile **de** parler français.

`facile` is an *attribut complément du verbe*,
`de parler français` is a *[complément d'objet indirect](http://grammaire.reverso.net/1_3_03_Le_complement_dobjet.shtml#header4)*.

It's the same construction in English:

> It is easy **to** speak French.

You can add the *[complément du comparatif](http://grammaire.reverso.net/3_1_14_complement_du_comparatif.shtml)* `plus ... que ...`:

> Parler anglais est **plus** facile **que** de parler français.

and with a negation:

> Parler anglais **n**'est **pas plus** facile **que** de parler français.

This sentence has the same grammatical structure as yours:

> Cette chose bien simple **n**'était **pas plus** facile, cependant, **que** de remuer le soleil !

2- You cannot remove `de` in the sentence, as you cannot remove it of

> Il est facile de parler français.
>   <strike>Il est facile parler français.</strike>

3- Other examples :

> Je suis désolé d'être arrivé en retard. (I'm sorry for being late)
>   Elle est obligée de partir. (She has to go/She is obliged to leave)
>   Je viens de penser à toi. (I just think of you)

Comment: On entend pourtant plus souvent dire « parler anglais est plus facile que parler français. » et « parler anglais n'est pas plus facile que parler français» que les versions avec « de ».

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, à l'oral l'omission est fréquente, mais à mon avis ce n'est pas plus correct que "j'aime pas l'école" (au lieu de "je **n**'aime pas"), que l'on entend beaucoup aussi...

Comment: I find this answer and that of @jlliagre equally instructive and "choose" the one by the member with a lower reputation score (as an encouragement to participation). Thanks to both!

Comment: jlliagre's answer is probably better than mine, but thanks for the encouragement !

Answer (score 5):

1. **What is its grammatical or syntactic function? (For example, is there a de-infinitive similar to the English to-infinitive?)**

   Not that similar but there should be a preposition between an adjective and an infinitive, e.g.

   - *Tricher est interdit.*
   - *Il est interdit **de** tricher.*
   - *Trouver la sortie est facile.*
   - *Il est facile **de** trouver la sortie.*
   - *La sortie est facile **à** trouver.*
2. **Would it be acceptable to delete de in the Flaubert sentence (i.e. have que remuer le soleil instead)? Would that be ungrammatical? Would it be grammatical but change the meaning?**

   That would break the quality of Flaubert prose but not grammar as that ***de*** is considered by current grammars to be syntactically expletive.

   Reference [tlfi: de](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de)

   > ***De** + inf. dans l'expression d'une comparaison.*
   >
   > − [**de** est facultatif dans le second terme d'une phrase qui énonce une préférence, un choix entre deux comportements (préférence de volonté plutôt que de goût).] **Plutôt souffrir que (de) mourir**.

   - « *Plutôt souffrir **que mourir**, c'est la devise des hommes.* »   **Jean de la Fontaine** - *La Mort et le Bûcheron.*
   - « *Face au monde qui change, il vaut mieux penser le changement **que changer** le pansement.* » **Jean Yanne** ;-)

   In any case, the meaning wouldn't change.

   Note that if the first infinitive is introduced by ***de***, then the second ***de*** is mandatory:

   - « *Il est plus facile **d**'embaucher que **de** licencier.* »
3. **What would be other usages for de + an infinitive? I.e. please give other sentence forms in which de would have the same syntactic role as described in answer to question 1.**

   > *Ils sont trop verts, dit-il, et bons pour des goujats.*
   >
   > *Fit-il pas mieux que **de** se plaindre ?*
   >
   > **Jean de la Fontaine** - *Le Renard et les Raisins*

   (See also [« Fit-il pas mieux que de se plaindre ? »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13211/fit-il-pas-mieux-que-de-se-plaindre) if your are confused by the last verse.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple comparative:

> Il est **plus facile de** marcher que **de nager**.
>
> Il est **plus facile de** se taire que **de parler** trop.

Negative:

> Il n'est pas plus bête de donner des exemples concrets que de faire la grammaire toute la journée.
>
> Le bateau pouvait **s’arrêter**, ils n’avaient qu’à descendre ; et cette chose bien simple n’était pas **plus facile**, cependant, **que de remuer** le soleil !

Now, the Flaubert sentence follows the same pattern, you just have to "dig it out":

> Il n'est pas **plus facile pour le bateau de s'arreter** **que [pour nous or some other thing like that] de remuer le soleil**.

The structure is the same but it is just not grouped together....