# C'en est une tout autre (que) (de) le suivre

Tags: prépositions, conjonctions

*Les embrouilles de Calma* de Barry Jonsberg :

Calma et Kiffo surveillent la maison du Pitbull, leur ennemi.

> Bon, je sais que je vous ai donné l'impression d'en avoir plus
> qu'assez de ce casuarina, mais je peux vous assurer qu'à l'instant de
> le quitter je l'ai trouvé des plus attrayants. Espionner la maison de
> quelqu'un est une chose, c'en est une tout autre **que** de le suivre
> dans des rues désertes à des heures indues du petit matin.

Quelle phrase entre les deux suivantes est plus littéraire ?

> C'en est une tout autre **que** de le suivre dans des rues désertes à
> des heures indues du petit matin.
>
> C'en est une tout autre **de** le suivre dans des rues désertes à des
> heures indues du petit matin.

Il est impossible d'omettre "que" et "de" ensemble, si ?

> C'en est une tout autre le suivre dans des rues désertes à des heures
> indues du petit matin.

Comment: J'aime beaucoup ce livre.

Comment: On ne peut pas omettre *de* (ou alors c'est du français franchement non conventionnel ? J'ai du mal.). Pour omettre *que*, il faudrait au moins une virgule à la place, et je crois que c'est effectivement peu littéraire.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas ce qui permet de ne pas citer la phrase complète. En tout cas, ce dialogue en anglais n'a jamais été littéraire. "C'en est une autre" ne peut pas se trouver en tête de phrase sans un antécédent.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Merci ! Cité du même livre _Serait-ce trop vous demander **que** de bien vouloir nous l'apporter ?_ Dans cette phrase, il est possible d'omettre "que" sans problème, non ?

Comment: @Oreste Là encore, non ou à la rigueur avec une longue pause. C'est plus flagrant ici parce que si on lit/entend « demander de », on a l'impression que la construction est « demander de faire quelque chose ». Effectivement on omettrait *que* en langue familière : « ça serait trop vous demander, de l'apporter ? ». Mais je bute en essayant de mélanger les deux : « \*serait-ce trop vous demander, de l'apporter » me paraît faux, et « ça serait trop vous demander que de l'apporter  » me paraît bizarre.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' D'accord. Mais, désolée, pourquoi il faut mettre une virgule dans la phrase _Ça serait trop vous demander **,** de l'apporter_ ? C'est une phrase simple, sans _serait-ce_ ni _bien vouloir_, donc il est possible d'écrire simplement _Ça serait trop vous demander **de** l'apporter_ ?

Comment: Quand je lis ou j'entends « Ça serait trop vous demander de l'apporter ? », je divise spontanément en « Ça serait trop » + « vous demander de l'apporter » et pas « Ça serait trop vous demander » + « l'apporter ».

Comment: Une question similaire : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20179/understanding-de-in-plus-facile-cependant-que-de-remuer-le-soleil

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, merci ! "Note that if the first infinitive is introduced by de, then the second de is mandatory: « Il est plus facile **d**'embaucher que **de** licencier. »" Oui, je suis d'accord, on peut omettre le 2ème "de", après "que". Je suis surprise par la 1ère réponse dans ce fil. Mais dans la phrase dans ma question, il est impossible d'omettre "de", elle a une structure différente.

Comment: Oui, elle a une structure différente. J'ai mis ce lien parce que la question m'a fait penser à *fit-il pas mieux que de se plaindre* que j'avais évoqué dans cette réponse et où *de* est indispensable, comme dans la phrase de ton livre.

Answer (score 2):

When you set up an equivalence in this structure, you connect the predicate and subject using *que*. This is one of its many uses and it has no real semantic content in this case.

> C'est un animal féroce que le lion !

We would probably insert a comma instead in English (and repeat the verb):

> They're fierce creatures, lions are!

But we don't phrase things in this way very often in the first place. We'd probably just stress the word *Lions* and pause slightly after it to get the same emphatic effect:

> Lions are fierce creatures!

So in your sentence:

> Espionner la maison de quelqu'un est une chose, c'en est une tout autre que de le suivre dans des rues désertes à des heures indues du petit matin.

We might translate roughly:

> Watching someone's house is one thing; following them in the deserted streets at ungodly hours of the morning is quite another.

Also good even if the parallelism is slightly weaker:

> Watching someone's house is one thing; it's quite another to follow them in the deserted streets at ungodly hours of the morning.

You can see the advantage of linking "quite another thing" and "following them" using *que*: it allows you to get the equivalence in *before* jumping into this long clause.

I once asked a French professor, the head of the linguistics department at my university, to explain why *que* is necessary here. He had a difficult time finding a reason for it, but said it would be worthwhile finding out.

---

You can't drop *de* here either, though I need to think about why. Here's a similar example from [« Je pensais pas »](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fe89_1EvOAw) by Daniel Lavoie:

> Je pensais pas qu'un jour j'aimerais si fort
>
> Que rêver de partir serait comme rêver de mourir
>
> Je pensais pas qu'un jour j'aimerais si fort
>
> Que j'aimerais mieux mourir que **de** partir encore

This is not the same syntax as your example, of course; this *que* is not an equivalence but a comparison. But intuitively I believe the *de* is there for the same reason.

Comment: I just do not understand how you say this is just "que" and not "que de". I am going to email the Dépannage folks. That last sentence has two verbs: mourir and que de partir. I cannot see a basic difference between that and the OP's example.

Comment: Ce n'est pas le fait de ne pas savoir pourquoi *que* et *de* sont nécessaires ici qui m'empêche d'être directeur d'un département de linguistique ? Bon à savoir ! Dans l'exemple de Lavoie, au on pourrait omettre *de* dans « … que (de) partir encore ». Comme par exemple dans le proverbe « mieux vaut partir que guérir ». Alors que je ne me vois pas omettre *de* dans l'exemple de la question.

Comment: Thank you. :) Voici ma phrase _Espionner la maison de quelqu'un est une chose, c'en est une tout autre **que de** le suivre dans des rues désertes à des heures indues du petit matin._ On peut omettre le "que", on ne peut pas omettre le "de".  Alors que dans la chanson de Lavoie _Que j'aimerais mieux mourir que **de** partir encore_ il est possible d'omettre "de", car c'est une comparaison. _J'aimerais mieux X que Y._ Ma phrase _X est une chose, c'est est une autre (que) de Y_.  Autrement dit, Y est une autre chose.

Comment: OK, j'ai une salade composée de "que et de "de" dans la tête, mais, à mon avis, il est possible d'omettre le "que" dans ma phrase, même sans y mettre une virgule, comme Gilles le conseille. J'aimerais que quelqu'un le confirme ou infirme.

Comment: _C'est une chose de dire que la mère est la première femme que connaîtra un homme, celle qui le marquera à jamais, c'en est une tout autre d'insinuer que leur rapport est plus intense que celui unissant une fille à sa mère._ [Devoir](https://www.ledevoir.com/lire/22373/une-ode-a-l-humanite-signee-aline-apostolska-les-hommes-et-sa-vie)

Comment: [Livres CA](https://books.google.ca/books?id=aIS_T5J8C5IC&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=%22C%27en+est+une+tout+autre%22&source=bl&ots=eYmkwD6o-k&sig=ACfU3U02v0nZYVor-yXlZW22Ll49QvRRHw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-9KCw_7T3AhXKKM0KHX1sAfUQ6AF6BAgWEAM#v=onepage&q=%22C'en%20est%20une%20tout%20autre%22&f=false) Les deux sources sont canadiennes. En bref, je vois des exemples avec _c'en est une tout autre de_ sur Internet.

Comment: I tend to interpret *que* and *de* as separate questions here since either one could appear on its own. *Il est utile de rêver.*

Comment: J'ai relu ta réponse et les comment.. Ma première impression c'est que je rejette la phrase sans _que_ ni _de_, mais je pense spontanément accepter celle avec _de_ seul. Dans les deux derniers ex. à [Gilles](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/50225/cen-est-une-tout-autre-que-de-le-suivre#comment104063_50225), la pause est inusitée pr moi et sa dernière phrase me paraît ampoulée. Je ne suis pas capable d'expliquer pourquoi oui, pourquoi non. Je pense que je trouve la phrase de la question lourde avec _tout_. Plus d'une chose sans doute, oui. cc @Gilles'SOnousesthostile'

Comment: I think we have the same situation in this passage from the story 'Le Personnage' by Gloria Escomel (1984): 'Ce récit, entrepris dans le seul but de te faire revivre - mais est-ce revivre que de se voir condamné a refaire des gestes anciens...'. This looks like the same way of expressing a structural equivalence between subject and predicate

Comment: @TomAdair That is a very interesting structure. Still I think I attach the *que* more to the *autre* here (e.g. *un autre que moi*). But knowing that *que de* **could** function together in that way does raise new possiblities / questions for me.

Answer (score 1):

*Il est impossible d'omettre "que" et "de" ensemble, si ?*

> Espionner la maison de quelqu'un est une chose, le suivre dans des
> rues désertes à des heures indues du petit matin en est une autre.

Le premier terme de la phrase (verbe à l'infinitif - [être] - attribut) devient le patron pour le deuxième.

Comment: Merci. Je voulais dire en gardant _c'en est une tout autre_.

Comment: Avec plaisir. BIen je comprends, j'ai simplement trouvé que c'était utile de voir ça, pour poursuivre la réflexion sur l'économie de la phrase. Je n'ai qu'un para. mais je ne trouve pas ce texte-là littéraire, avec ou sans. @Oreste

Answer (score -1):

**Que ou que de**

> La conjonction que est parfois employée pour établir une comparaison
> entre deux éléments, dans des formulations comme autant... que, il
> vaut mieux... que, préférer... plutôt que, etc. S’il précède un verbe
> à l’infinitif, que peut alors être suivi de la préposition de.
> Toutefois, celle-ci est facultative.

Exemples :

- Autant en **finir maintenant que de remettre** cela à plus tard. (ou : Autant en finir maintenant que remettre cela à plus tard.)
- Il vaut mieux **perdre la face que de perdre la tête**. (ou : Il vaut mieux perdre la face que perdre la tête.)
- N’aimes-tu pas mieux **marcher avec moi que d’y aller en voiture**? (ou : N’aimes-tu pas mieux marcher avec moi qu’y aller en voiture?)
- Je préfère **manger moins mais mieux plutôt que de manger moins bien** mais plus. (ou : Je préfère manger moins mais mieux plutôt que manger moins bien mais plus.)

[Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=que%20de&id=3892)

La phrase donnée par l'OP:

**Espionner la maison de quelqu'un est une chose**, c'en est une tout autre **que de** **le suivre dans des rues désertes à des heures indues du petit matin**.

Here are examples of **que de** which are not comparisons, but rather a relative pronoun que followed by a partitive article:

**Que de** hargne ! Tu insistes **alors que** *de nombreux participants* ont expliqué ton erreur. Il ne faut pourtant que *de faibles capacités* d'observation pour *se rendre compte de que* **de** nombreux mots peuvent avoir plusieurs usages différents. J'espère **que de** cet épisode, tu retiendras quelque chose...

In fact, *alors que* is one phrase and *de nombreux participants* is another. So, technically, this is not "de que" as a unit of comparison as given by verbs as in the Dépannage examples above. The same applies to *de faibles capacités*. *Il ne faut pourtant que* [something] which  here is: "de faible capacités". "de nombreux mots" is the same thing. Those are all the relative pronoun "que" followed by a partitive article *de.*

The last *que de* comes from how the sentence is structured. An alternative construction of the last sentence: "J'espère *que* tu retiendras quelque chose *de* cet épisode" shows that this is not **que de**.

**Nothing but** ranting! You are insisting [on being right] whereas many participants explained your mistake. Yet one need only have [some] weak abilities of observation to realize that many words can have several different uses. I hope that you will retain something from this episode.

[It's interesting to note how the French partitive article is not needed in translation in all cases in English although it can be *some* in some cases.]

Comment: Ça n'a rien à voir, erreur.

Comment: @LPH En quel sens?

Comment: Ce n'est pas la même tournure ; celle que vous identifiez est une tournure de comparaison dans laquelle on ne peut jamais se passer de « que ».

Comment: **Espionner la maison** se compare à **le suivre dans les rues désertes** Il s'agit clairement d'une comparaison ici.

Comment: Non, c'est une erreur, et quelqu'un d'autre va bientôt vous le redire.

Comment: Je confirme : il ne s'agit pas de la même tournure.

Comment: @Oreste Il y a clairement une comparaison. Je suis vraiment choquée par vos réactions.

Comment: Non, il y a une sorte de comparaison avec « tout autre » mais elle n'a rien à voir avec la question. On aurait la même tournure grammaticale par exemple dans « C'est une chose difficile que de suivre quelqu'un dans des rues désertes ».

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile'« C'est une chose difficile que de suivre quelqu'un dans des rues désertes » Oui, d'accord. Mais la phrase ici c'est: Espionner la maison de quelqu'un est *une chose*, c'en est une tout *autre* que de le suivre dans des rues désertes.  est une comparaison entre **une chose et tout autre [chose]**.

Comment: Comment nier la comparaison? Le fait que l'on peut utiliser "que de" sans comparaison ne veut pas dire que quand il y a une comparaison cela ne marche pas comme indiqué par la Banque de dépannage linguistique? J'attends vos réponses.

Comment: Le mot *que* a beaucoup d'usages différents. C'est un des mots les plus compliqués du français. La construction grammaticale dans la question n'est pas la même que celle des exemples dans ta réponse. Dans les deux cas il se trouve que la suite de mots « que de » apparaît, mais le mot *que* n'y joue pas le même rôle. Le contenu de ta réponse est correct en lui-même, mais il n'a rien à voir avec la question.

Comment: « C'est une tout autre chose » est synonyme, plus ou moins, de « c'est une chose différente de » ; un état de l'existence d'une différence n'est pas une comparaison grammaticale ; il est le résultat d'une comparaison qui a été faite dans l'esprit de quelqu'un mais tout ça c'était dans l'esprit de quelqu'un, et il est possible qu'on n'y pense même plus. Il n'y a pas comparaison grammaticale.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Comment justifier ou prouver ou montrer que la phrase d''Oreste ne contient pas une comparaison? C'est de la folie, il me semble.

Comment: Dans ta réponse : _Je préfère X plutôt que Y._ Une comparaison, c'est l'idée principale de cette phrase. Dans ma question : _X que de Y_ . La structure est différente.

Comment: @LPH Oh, la "comparaison doit être grammaticale". Quelle ambiguité.

Comment: @Oreste Dans ma question : "X que de Y . La structure est différente". – Non, il y a deux verbes: **Espionner la maison comparer** à **suivre dans les rues**. Comparer: N’aimes-tu pas mieux **marcher avec moi que d’y aller** en voiture?

Comment: Puisque vous insistez que c'est une comparaison, dites-nous de quel type de comparaison il s'agit, dites-nous quels sont les types possibles (il n'y en a pas 36).

Comment: **Que de** hargne ! Tu insistes alors **que de** nombreux participants ont expliqué ton erreur. Il ne faut pourtant **que de** faibles capacités d'observation pour se rendre compte de **que de** nombreux mots peuvent avoir plusieurs usages différents. J'espère **que de** cet épisode, tu retiendras quelque chose...

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile Frankly, nothing but [que de] a rant from you. All those "que de" are not like the "que de" in the OP's sentence at all.  And none of those in your comment compare anything to anything. I'm sorry you felt you need to be so rude to me. I know "que de" can be used in other circumstances.

Comment: It's not a grammatical comparative (plus, moins, aussi...) but does *imply* that one action is more intrusive/invasive than the other. But in my opinion that's not related to the reason for the use of either *que* or *de* (even though *que* especially is also used in the grammatical comparative). I think the reason for the use of *que* is definitely the one in my answer; otherwise *espionner la maison* would be both "une chose" and "une tout autre".

Comment: @LukeSawczak I do think the "que" can be dropped, but I fail to see how this entire French sentence which holds together as one structure, could include what you gave as another structure: c'est un animal féroce que le lion !. Your translations are fine but the analysis seems off to me....